# Can I delete ‘then’ in ‘and then’？

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence and it bounced along the pavement **and then** disappeared down a drain.

How to understand the **then**, and why not only use **and** instead of **and then**.

Comment: **Then** has the sense of 'the next thing that happened was', so it isn't strictly necessary in your sentence. Obviously the coin fell down the drain _after_ bouncing along the pavement.

Comment: @KateBunting If what you said are right, why not say: ' he dropped his fifty pence and then it bounced along the pavement and then disappeared down a drain.

Comment: In that sentence, the first 'then' is _even less_ necessary than the second! It's even more obvious that the coin bounced _after_ it was dropped.

Comment: So, whether in the first place or the second place, we can use **and** or **and then**. Am I right?

Comment: You asked "Why not only use _and_?" I was trying to explain that it's fine to use _and_ on its own, unless you particularly need to point out the order in which things happened.

Answer (score 1):

On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence and it bounced along the pavement and then disappeared down a drain.

Q.

> **How to understand the then, and why not only use and instead of and then?**

In this case, "**then" denotes the next step** in a series of actions

Yes you can use **and** instead of and then or you could use **it then**

*On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence and it bounced along the pavement **and then** disappeared down a drain.*

*On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence and it bounced along the pavement **and** disappeared down a drain.*

*On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence and it bounced along the pavement, it then disappeared down a drain.*

you could also say

**On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty **pence, it** bounced along the pavement **before** disappeared down a drain**.

*On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence, **after bouncing** along the pavement **it** disappeared into a drain.*

All the above mean the same thing

Comment: Why not say: ' he dropped his fifty pence **and then** it bounced along the pavement **and then** disappeared down a drain.

Answer (score 1):

All these work (roll is better than  bounce for a coin):

On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence,  it rolled along the pavement and then disappeared down a drain. typical English structure: A, B **and** C

On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence and it bounced along the pavement, then disappeared down a drain. emphasis dropped and bounced as "equally important".

On his way to the sweet shop, he dropped his fifty pence and it bounced along the pavement and then disappeared down a drain. [too many ands here. It sounds stylistically heavy and unnecessary but it  not ungrammatical.]

And the word then can be taken out of all three. Then is a discourse marker, often used in narration.